# Legacy Database CarrierWave Integration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, activeadmin, legacy

I am having legacy database
Rails 3.2 & ruby 1.9.3p448
I wanted to develop active_admin back-end application 
I wanted use CarrierWave File Uploads gem for uploading image
Following is my code in admin/item_master.rb i.e in view

```
  form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|

    f.inputs "Item Details" do
      f.input :IMTNAME
      f.input :IMTBRIEFDESC
      f.input :IMTDETAILDESC
      f.input :IMTIMAGE, :as => :file
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

Following is my code in model

```
class ItemMaster < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "MDIMT"

  attr_accessible :IMTNAME, :IMTBRIEFDESC, :IMTDETAILDESC, :IMTIMAGE

  mount_uploader :IMTIMAGE, ImtimageUploader
end
```

It givesme Following Error

```
NameError in Admin::ItemMastersController#update
uninitialized constant IMTIMAGE
```

Comment: What does your ImtimageUploader class contain? I'm fairly certain the issue is due to the uppercase attribute name.

Comment: Yes it is due to the UPPERCASE attribute issue.For that I have also tried override attribute accessors but it wont helpful. Is there any Way to make all attribute in lowercase?

Comment: Can you post a more detailed backtrace? In my testing of Ruby, methods can begin with uppercase characters, but any time they are invoked they must be followed by parentheses. The problem may be in how those methods are invoked and it might not necessarily by in the CarrierWave code. There could be potential issues in other areas like the form builder.

Comment: You might try using [alias_attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-alias_attribute) as documented in the Rails API. That might allow CarrierWave to work as advertised.